# Unable to change browser theme color in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, themes, head

I've been trying to change the theme-color (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android) by adding the meta to the  and using the following plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/browser-theme-color/ but it just does not seem to work. Also used other plugins such as Mobile Address Bar Changer
 and Chrome Theme Color Changer.

Hope someone can give some pointers

Answer (score 1):

Just put following code before `</head>` in your `header.php` file with every color you want.

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ef2121" />
```

Also keep in mind it just works on some mobile browsers.

Comment: i tried doing that right from the start.. just tried again with the plugin disabled.. it still doesn't work.. I can see the theme-colors on other websites.. just doesn't work with mine...

Comment: @KaiyanLeong Did you check for probably creating this `meta` by some JavaScript that you don't know about? You can check page-resource in your browser and search for `theme-color`

Comment: sorry I'm still very new at this.. I checked on the page-resource in a browser and it seems to be pulling a different header...

Comment: @KaiyanLeong I can look at your website (if you don't mind) maybe I could help.

Comment: of course not! would love to get some help.. the site is https://saltmagazine.asia

Comment: @KaiyanLeong I've checked your page, I found no problem. Which browsers did you test your website with? Put the `meta` in `<head>` and try it with Google Chrome on mobile phone (not tablet nor desktop) if you haven't before.

Comment: I'm using Chrome on my android.. I can see the theme-color of other websites.. this is my header.php file http://tinypic.com/r/2aqdlf/9 and this is what I see from page source http://tinypic.com/r/1624mr8/9

Comment: @KaiyanLeong What I saw is totally different with your actual page resources. You sure you are using the same header file? I'm using different headers for different pages. Their names would be something like: `header.php`, `header-single.php` and etc,. I see you are using a plugin for showing website is at building. Probably that plugin is re-writing your `meta`s. Deactivate it and check again.